# Removing white spaces in sql field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with three  fields `(ID , machine_name, carpark_id)` two  of the machine names has `(311A__) _ =spaces  and (311B__)`  how to select and insert rows into machine name which have spaces in it.

```
   sql_local = """SELECT id FROM customer_1.pay_machines WHERE machine_name="%s" """ % machine

   sql_local = """INSERT INTO customer_1.pay_machines (machine_name, carpark_id) VALUES ("%s", 0)""" % machine

   sql_local = """SELECT id FROM customer_1.pay_machines WHERE machine_name="%s" """ % machine

   sql_local = """INSERT INTO customer_1.pay_and_display (plate, machine_id, ticket_datetime, expiry_datetime, ticket_name, ticket_price) VALUES ("%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s") """ % (plate, machineId, entryDatetime, expiryDatetime, ticketName, ticketPrice)
```

Comment: If you put quotes around your strings it won't matter if there's spaces..

Comment: You stated: "select and insert rows into machine name which have spaces in it.". You did not state the issue is that MySQL is trimming spaced AT THE END of the string. You should reformulate your question well.

Comment: Ah yes, I missed the fact they were trailing spaces..

Comment: @preethi , do you have an update for us?

Answer (score 1):

I know what problem you are having!

MySQL always auto-trims your string, so inserting 'a   ' will actually be just 'a'.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html

"For VARCHAR columns, trailing spaces in excess of the column length are truncated prior to insertion and a warning is generated, regardless of the SQL mode in use. For CHAR columns, truncation of excess trailing spaces from inserted values is performed silently regardless of the SQL mode."

**You can try using a blob, which will not ignore whitespaces**

If you want to continue to use CHAR or VARCHAR fields, you can use `LIKE 'String  '` to include whitespaces, `WHERE col = 'String    '` will not work

Answer (score -1):

Filtering machine with space: where machine like '% %';

Insert: What is the problem? Just put the name with the space between the single quotes.

I notice you are using double quotes instead of single quote, the usual string delimiter in MySQL.

Comment: It won't matter if you put qoutes or not, MySQL auto-trims every string putted into a CHAR or VARCHAR field.

Comment: You stated: "select and insert rows into machine name which have spaces in it.". You did not state the issue is that MySQL is trimming spaced AT THE END of the string. You should reformulate your question well.